# Failed to connect to a SMTP server

Tags: c++, winapi, smtp, winsock2

I created a simple code to connect to a Gmail SMTP server, but the function `connect()` returns `-1 (SOCKET_ERROR)`.  What's wrong with this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("smtp.gmail.com");
    addr.sin_port = htons(587);

    //WSA STARTUP
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to startup wsa.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // GNIAZDO DLA KLIENTA
    SOCKET mSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (mSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Socket error: " << WSAGetLastError();
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //LACZENIE Z SERWEREM
    int status = connect(mSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    std::cout << "Connection status: " << status;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inet_addr` expects an IP address in dot notation, as in `"1.2.3.4"`. It does not resolve domain names. You are looking for [`getaddrinfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo)

Answer (score 3):

The answer below is correct, but since you are using Windows, an easier option is [WSAConnectByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaconnectbynamew) which avoids all the old-fashioned htons/getaddrinfo stuff and also works with IPv6 automatically.